# When does setting 'perl=TRUE' in 'strsplit' does not work (as intended or at all)?

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I just did some benchmarking while trying to optimise some code and observed that `strsplit` with `perl=TRUE` is *faster* than running `strsplit` with `perl=FALSE`. For example,

```
set.seed(1)
ff <- function() paste(sample(10), collapse= " ")
xx <- replicate(1e5, ff())

system.time(t1 <- strsplit(xx, "[ ]"))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.246   0.002   1.268 

system.time(t2 <- strsplit(xx, "[ ]", perl=TRUE))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.389   0.001   0.392 

identical(t1, t2) 
# [1] TRUE
```

So my question (or rather a variation of the question in the title) is, under what circumstances would be absolutely need `perl=FALSE` (leaving out the `fixed` and `useBytes` parameters)? In other words, what can't we do using `perl=TRUE` that can be done by setting `perl=FALSE`?

Comment: I think `perl=FALSE` is just a design choice, since it is not yet implemented in some regex function ( like `regexec`). Maybe `perl=TRUE` will be the default value in the future R versions.

Comment: @agstudy The benefits would have to be _extremely_ compelling to R Core because changing a default like that would break a _ton_ of existing code.

Comment: @joran good point. But if the benefits is proved to be in all cases , why not to add a sort of "good warning"or "global settings", to encourage the use of PCRE...

Comment: or even just a `options(perl.default = TRUE)`

Comment: @agstudy I have no strong feelings either way. I'm just saying, based on what I have observed on the r-devel mailing list, R Core is quite conservative when it comes to changes that break existing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expressions in base R: 'perl=TRUE' vs. the default (PCRE vs. TRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240375/regular-expressions-in-base-r-perl-true-vs-the-default-pcre-vs-tre)

Answer (score 2):

from the documentation ;)

> Performance considerations
>
> If you are doing a lot of regular expression matching, including on very long strings, you will want to consider the options used. Generally PCRE will be faster than the default regular expression engine, and fixed = TRUE faster still (especially when each pattern is matched only a few times).

Of course, this does not answer the question of "are there any dangers to always using `perl=TRUE`"

Comment: This helps. But I'd like to know specifically, if there are cases where `perl=TRUE` breaks.