# Extract a substring between two words from a string

Tags: regex, string, r, substr

I have the following string:

```
string = "asflkjsdhlkjsdhglk<body>Iwant\to+extr@ctth!sstr|ng<body>sdgdfsghsghsgh"
```

I would like to extract the string between the two `<body>` tags. The result I am looking for is:

```
substring = "<body>Iwant\to+extr@ctth!sstr|ng<body>"
```

Note that the substring between the two `<body>` tags can contain letters, numbers, punctuation and special characters.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe this `<body>[\S\s]*<body>`

Answer (score 7):

Here is the regular expression way:

```
regmatches(string, regexpr('<body>.+<body>', string))
```

Comment: Why do you need the perl = TRUE in this?

Comment: @Codoremifa you don't, thanks. Originally, I thought OP wanted to exclude the tags, to which I suggested using lookahead assertions, requiring the `perl=TRUE` flag.

Comment: One advantage of `perl=TRUE` is that [it's faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757534/when-does-setting-perl-true-in-strsplit-does-not-work-as-intended-or-at-all).

Comment: @Arun no kidding. Thanks, I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 6):

```
regex = '<body>.+?<body>'
```

You want the non-greedy (`.+?`), so that it doesn't group as many `<body>` tags as possible.

If you're solely using a regex  with no auxiliary functions, you're going to need a capturing group to extract what is required, ie:

```
regex = '(<body>.+?<body>)'
```

Answer (score 2):

strsplit() should help you:

```
>string = "asflkjsdhlkjsdhglk<body>Iwant\to+extr@ctth!sstr|ng<body>sdgdfsghsghsgh"
>x = strsplit(string, '<body>', fixed = FALSE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] "asflkjsdhlkjsdhglk"         "Iwant\to+extr@ctth!sstr|ng" "sdgdfsghsghsgh"  
> x[[1]][2]
[1] "Iwant\to+extr@ctth!sstr|ng"
```

Of course, this gives you all three parts of the string and does not include the  tag.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the body tags in your solution gets excluded. I want them to be returned as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Matthew's and Steve's answers are both acceptable.  Here is another solution:

```html
string = "asflkjsdhlkjsdhglk<body>Iwant\to+extr@ctth!sstr|ng<body>sdgdfsghsghsgh"

regmatches(string, regexpr('<body>.+<body>', string))

output = sub(".*(<body>.+<body>).*", "\\1", string)

print (output)
```